# Oracle PL/SQL BULK Update from an arrray

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is it possible to perform a bulk update in Oracle like this:

```
TYPE type_A IS RECORD
(
    var    NUMBER(15,2)
);

TYPE t_type_A IS VARRAY (9) OF type_A; 
var_t_type_A  t_type_A;


SELECT
    A
BULK COLLECT INTO var_t_type_A
FROM
    B;
    
-- lopp over

FOR i IN var_t_type_A.FIRST .. var_t_type_A.LAST
LOOP
    var_t_type_A.var = 99;
END LOOP;
```

And theh just similiar with insert do like this

```
   FORALL var_i_idx IN 1..table_of_t_created_new_buchung.count SAVE EXCEPTIONS
       UPDATE TABLE B somehow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your skeleton code is rather sparse so by necessity so is any answer. First off, Yes, what you seen to want is possible. Secondly you have a couple issues in you code:

1. There is no reason to create a record for a to contain a single
   variable.
2. I *assume*  a varray would works with bulk collect/ forall. I have
   just **never** used one, never saw the point.
3. Your forall statement contains the "save exceptions" clause, however
   without an exception section this is useless. I have included the
   necessary definitions for that.

```
    declare 
        bulk_errors  EXCEPTION;  
        PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (bulk_errors , -24381);  
        
        type t_type_a is table of number(15,2);  
        var_t_type_a  t_type_a;
    
    begin
    
    
        select a
          bulk collect 
          into var_t_type_a
          from b;
        
        -- lopp over
    
        for i in var_t_type_a.first .. var_t_type_a.last
        loop
            var_t_type_a(i) = 99;
        end loop;
        
        ...
    
    
        forall var_i_idx in 1..var_t_type_a.count save exceptions
           update table b 
              set some_column = var_t_type_a(var_i_indx); 
              
    exception
        when bulk_errors then 
             <logic for bulk errors>;
    end ;
```

For a more complete answer post a more complete problem description.

Comment: Thanks! I try always to put a simpe code in order to be specific and just to keep it simple. A more complete answer is not needed. I will try if this works

Comment: Simple is good, but simplistic is not. Be careful of crossing the line. At any rate, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can be done with an update, but what about a global temporary table instead of array type.

Something like:

```
create global temporary table temp_table (xid rowid, value number(15, 2));

insert into temp_table select rowid, value from main_table;

update temp_table ....

update (select m.value v1, t.value v2
          from main_table m 
           join temp_table t on m.rowid = t.xid)
   set v1 = v2
```